# Overriding in chain of dependencies

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, unity-container

I'm new to Unity. I have 3 classes like this

```
ClassA(ClassB b)
ClassB(ClassC c)
public class ClassC
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And when runtime I have `classC.Name = "foo"`, my question is how can I Resolve `<ClassA>` using `classC`? Should I create factory method to resolve `ClassB` first using `ClassC` then resolve `ClassA` using `ClassB`?

Is there better approach?

Comment: Can you explain what do you mean by `when runtime I have classC.Name = "foo"`?

Comment: I mean I have an object of ClassC when runtime, for example, it's selected from a list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understand, you have some class, say `ClientClass`, that needs to create an instance of `ClassA` given an instance of `ClassC`.

For example:

```
public class ClientClass
{
    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        ClassC class_c = ...
        ClassA class_a = CreateClassA(class_c);
    }
}
```

So what this means is that `ClientClass` needs a dependency that looks like this:

```
public interface IClassAFactory
{
    ClassA Create(ClassC class_c);
}
```

This dependency is called a factory, it allows you to create other dependencies.

Now, before you decide that you need a factory, see if you can meet your requirements without one. Take a look at [this article](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=99).

If you decide that you want a factory, define the above interface in the same assembly that needs it (where `ClientClass` lives).

And then you need to create an implementation of such factory that uses the container to create the `ClassA` object.

Here is how such factory looks like:

```
public class UnityBasedClassAFactory : IClassAFactory
{
    private readonly IUnityContainer m_Container;

    public UnityBasedClassAFactory(IUnityContainer container)
    {
        m_Container = container;
    }

    public ClassA Create(ClassC class_c)
    {
        return m_Container.Resolve<ClassA>(new DependencyOverride<ClassC>(class_c));
    }
}
```

Please note that this factory class needs to exist in the [Composition Root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/). If you create it in any other place, this would mean that you are using the [Service Locator anti-pattern](http://yacoubsoftware.blogspot.com/2015/10/object-composability-another-reason-why.html).

Now, you need to inject the factory interface into `ClientClass` like this:

```
public class ClientClass
{
    private readonly IClassAFactory m_ClassAFactory;

    public ClientClass(IClassAFactory class_a_factory)
    {
        m_ClassAFactory = class_a_factory;
    }

    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        ClassC class_c = ...; //runtime value
        ClassA class_a = m_ClassAFactory.Create(class_c);
    }
}
```

Now, all you need to do is register the factory in your Composition Root like this:

```
container.RegisterType<IClassAFactory, UnityBasedClassAFactory>();
```

Comment: Thanks for the links, actually this one solves my problem
`new DependencyOverride<ClassC>(class_c)`
Didn't know it can override params in chain.

Comment: Hi Yacoub, I get another case that needs factory now, I will apply your solution, but my question is: Is passing container to UnityBasedClassAFactory the right way?

Comment: @kvuong, as long as the factory lives in the Composition Root.